# deleting values of column and then putting values in increasing order

Tags: mysql, database

I have populated 100 records in a test table with all the rows having same content. For example, if I have a column in the table with name `BatchId_bi` then, for all the rows starting from 1 to 100, I have value 100 inserted for this column. Similarly, all other rows are identical. This is creating me problem in tracking duplicate records when I am inserting these records to another database.

Is there a way, I can delete all the 100 values for the column `BatchId_bi` and insert values from `1` for row1,`2` for row 2 and so on until `100` for row 100. this will make more sense to me.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for this

> Drop A Column

```
ALTER TABLE test_table DROP BatchId_bi
```

> Add AutoIncremnt Column

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD BatchId_bi INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

> If you want increment start with 101 then try this

```
ALTER TABLE test_table AUTO_INCREMENT=101;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am looking for deleting the contents of the column keeping the column name intact. Also, I already have another field which is a primary key and hence wondering if there is another way to do what I want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way, I can insert numbers like `101` for row 1, `102` for row 2 etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up  BatchId_bi as an auto increment key is the best option.
   Otherwise you can try this as a work around

```
update TABLE set BatchId_bi = 0 ; 
replace into TABLE(BatchId_bi,[all your columns])
select @a:=@a+1 AS  BatchId_bi,[all your columns] from(select @a:=0) A ,TABLE B
;
delete from TABLE where BatchId_bi = 0 ;
```