# all columns values are getting deleted

Tags: mysql, database

Right now,`TableId_int` column has identical values for 1000 records which is equal to `1` 
When I run the following three SQL Statements simultaneously in MYSQL Workbench editor
against a database  "Mydb" and table "Mytable"

```
update Mydb.Mytable set TableId_int = 0 ; 

REPLACE into Mydb.Mytable(TableId_int)
SELECT @a:=@a+1 AS  TableId_int from(SELECT @a:=0) A ,Mydb.Mytable B;




DELETE from Mydb.Mytable where TableId_int = 0 ;
```

All the records gets deleted except the one in the column `TableId_int`. I can see the 
values in the column `TableId_int` starting from `1` to `1000` for 1000 records but all other
column values gets deleted and are empty which I don't want. I want to keep all other 
column values intact.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

I am referring to following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829474/deleting-values-of-column-and-then-putting-values-in-increasing-order/22829587#22829587) for my answer. There, people have suggested, that
Setting up `TableId_int` as an auto increment key is the best option but I already have another
table column set as primary key and auto increment and hence MySQL won't allow me to set 
another autoincrement.

Please advise what should I do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `REPLACE` does a `DELETE` followed by an `INSERT`. If you don't specify values for the other columns, the `INSERT` part can't infer their values, and it doesn't use what was there before, except for the primary key.

I assume `TableId_int` is a primary or unique key, and that means an existing row with the same value is going to be *replaced*. That is, deleted and then inserted.

You could simply use an `UPDATE` to do this:

```
UPDATE (SELECT @a:=0) A, Mydb.Mytable B SET B.TableId_int = (@a:=@a+1);
```

But I have to comment that it looks like you're trying to renumber primary key values to be consecutive.  This is not recommended, nor is it necessary. Auto-increment primary key values need to be *unique* but they don't need to be consecutive. They are not row numbers, they only identify each row. It's normal for there to be gaps, from deletions, rollbacks, failed inserts, etc.

Comment: `TableId_int` is not a primary key. It's datatype is `int(20) UN`.